# Вложенные массивы С# unity

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d

Прошу не нападать на меня, если ответ на поверхности, а я не нашёл. Лучше тыкните носом :-). Задача такова - есть необходимость в 50-ти массивах типа "string", далее идёт необходимость удобной навигации по ним. Пробовал через string[,], но так получается 2d массив обычных строк(не массивов). С list<string[]> не разобрался, как минимум - не могу добиться отображения в инспекторе.
Резюмируя - Нужен массив массивов 1 на 50 шт., отображение в инспекторе. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого, вам нужно использовать структуру:

```
public BatyaMassivov[] ma;

public struct BatyaMassivov{
public stirng[] mas;
}
```

Далее в инспекторе поставьте цифру 50, и вам вылезет 50 массивов

Comment: В инспекторе же будет также 50 строк подряд в столбик?

Comment: Максим, да, но там будет массивы, которые можно изменить

Comment: Здоровья тебе крепкого, спасибо, действительно под носом ответа не видел.