# Unity C# Сохранение вложенного массива в PlayerPrefs

Tags: c#, unity3d, save

На днях просил помощи в создании вложенного + отображаемого в инспекторе массива (Ссылка на вопрос - [Вложенные массивы С# unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1250385/%d0%92%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%a1-unity/1250395#1250395)).
Теперь все работает через похожую структуру

```
public _MyArraysStruct[] _MyArrays;
public struct _MyArraysStruct{
public stirng[] mas;
}
```

Где 50 массивов содержит по массиву на 50 элементов в каждом. Задача - сохранить в PlayerPrefs сразу все данные.

На данный момент, для решения другой задачи, пользуюсь следующим методом сохранения

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("Save", JsonUtility.ToJson(MyClass));
```

Где класс содержит в себе 3 массива типа Float и пару массивов string.
Всё успешно сохраняет.

А при решении текущей задачи (Описана выше) происходит следующее - как не пробовал сохранять, могу сохранить только обращаясь к конкретному элементу массива

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("Test_Save", JsonUtility.ToJson(_MyArrays[0]));
```

Сам элемент содержит в себе string массив на 50 элементов и успешно сохраняет их, а вот сохранить одним махом всё - не выходит. Не писать же 50 раз, создавая 50 разных сейв-файлов команду сохранения.
Буду безмерно благодарен за помощь.

p.s.Заранее прошу прощения, если мой вопрос плохо читаемый, сказывается усталость...

Comment: Возмите нормальный сериализатор - `Newtonsoft.Json` или `System.Text.Json`. В Unity родной сериализатор умеет только примитивные штуки делать.

Comment: чтобы `Newtonsoft.Json` работал, нужно создать папочку `Plugins` и туда закинуть библиотеку ньютона, а дальше там ничего сложного: два метода и вуаля. [ссылка](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

Comment: @aepot, разве Newtonsoft.Json умеет массив структур сериализовать?

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer он даже носки стирать и шнурки гладить умеет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё дело в том, что вы хотите в JSON  перевести массив структур.
Для того, что бы это сделать, надо структуру с массивом перенести в другую структуру:

```
public struct st1{
    public string[] gg;
}
public struct st2{
    public st1[] struct1;
}
```

Что бы сериализовать в JSON, нужно сделать следующее:

```
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(st2);
```

Для десериализации, нужно сделать так:

```
st2 struct2 = JsonUtility.FromJson<st2>(json);
```

Вообще, я вам бы не советовал сохранять столь **большое** количество текста в `PlayerPrefs`, куда лучше сохранить в память устройства

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, создание текстового файла в папке с приложением?
И в чём может заключатся проблема сохранения в ```PlayerPrefs```?

Просто я сомневаюсь, что для моих целей, сортировки и, позже, удобной навигации, подойдёт текстовый файл. На данный момент, все необходимые мне действия мгновенно выполняются с массивом, размер которого создан огромным для теста производительности, на 500 000 элементов.

Comment: Я тоже использовал подобную фишку и писал 2 функции конвертации с одного типа в другой, но в моей игре было мало данных.                 
Вам пожалуй больше подойдёт один из сериализаторов например FullSerializer: https://github.com/jacobdufault/fullserializer

Comment: Кстати есть вариант конструктора кастомных инспекторов: https://github.com/slavniyteo/one-line/blob/master/Documentation~/README.md